# Prove that $G$ is cyclic if $|G|=15$ and $G$ has only one subgroup each of orders $3$ and $5$

Tags: group-theory

> Question:
>
> Let $\left | G \right |=15$. If G has only one subgroup of order 3 and only one subgroup of order 5, prove that G is cyclic.

Looking for useful **hints** to the above question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Counterproof: If G were cyclic, it would be O.

Comment: @Dronz What? $\Bbb Z/15\Bbb Z$ has that property.

Comment: Version without extra hypothesis about subgroups: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67407 Generalization to all orders with the hypothesis about subgroups: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1302635/a-finite-group-which-has-a-unique-subgroup-of-order-d-for-each-d-mid-n

Comment: @G.Sassatelli It was a joke about the shape of the capital letter G.

Answer (score 12):

Pick an element of $G$ not in either of those subgroups. What must that element's order be?

Comment: Love this answer.

Comment: This is pure elegance!

Answer (score 10):

Some hinting:

(1) If a finite group has one unique subgroup of some given order, then that subgroup is *normal*

(2) If $\;N,H\lhd G\;$ and $\;G=NH\;$ , then in fact $\;G=NH\cong N\times H\;$

(3) Direct product of finite cyclic groups is cyclic if the groups' orders are coprime.

By the way, you don't need that "if" in the question: the condition is **always** fulfilled.

Comment: Good point, 3 does not divide 4 :)

Comment: @almagest Thank you but I didn't get your point...

Comment: I seem to remember that $p\ne1\bmod q$ and $q\ne1\bmod p$ is the standard test for groups of order $pq$.

Comment: @almagest Oh, that. Yes, of course you're right...but that is when you use Sylow theorems. In this case we aren't told it is possible...and besides we don't need it as it is *assumed* the subgroups are already normal. Thank you.

Comment: "You don't need that "if""... tell that to Schur and Zassenhaus

Comment: @Soke Thank you. I would, yet I think they're already pretty dead so I don't think they'll address my question...:) Anyway, my intention was to hint towards the fact that there's one unique group, up to isomorphism, of order $\;15\;$ : the cyclic one, and such a group **always** has normal Sylow subgroups.

Comment: Yup. In general, if $p < q$ and $p \not\mid q-1$, then the only group of order $pq$ is the cyclic one.

Comment: Could you please provide explanations on why these statements are true?

Comment: @Hristmar Where are you stuck and what is your background in group theory?

Comment: I dont even know where to begin proving those. My background is that i've failed my exam 2 times in a row. I've checked my notes but they statements are nowhere to be found. I assume they can be concluded from other statements but I'm still searching.

Comment: @Hristmar Well, then perhaps you should write down a formal question  for each thing that bothers you, and accompany it with your best shot at solving that problem that you can.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Let $T$ the subgroup of order $3$, $F$ the subgroup of order $5$. Show that each of them is normal in $G$ and $G=TF$. Then use the *Chinese remainder theorem*.