# What finite groups have unique cyclic subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $n$.  If $G$ is cyclic, we then know that are subgroups are cyclic are are unique.  If $G=\langle x\rangle$, and $d|n$, then $\langle x^d\rangle$ is the unique cyclic subgroup of order $\frac{n}{d}$.

However, suppose we know that the group $G$ has a unique subgroup of order $d$ for any $d$ such that $d|n$.  What else can we say about $G$? Does it have to be cyclic? Can it be factorizable over subgroup $H$ and $K$?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: See the posted solutions to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59903/finite-subgroups-of-the-multiplicative-group-of-a-field-are-cyclic)

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why I couldn't find that question earlier.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1302635/11619) could be a duplicate target. It is a duplicate of quite a few other questions already.

Answer (score 3):

This condition implies that the Sylow $p$-subgroup of $p$ is unique
and cyclic. This implies that $G$ is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups, so is cyclic.

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  I was hoping that there would be something that I was missing, but I wasn't 100% positive.  Thank you.