# Let $G$ be a group of order $n$. $G$ has one and only one subgroup of order of every divisor of $n$. Then G is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$G$ be a group of order $n$. $G$ has one and only one subgroup of order of every divisor of $n$. Then G is cyclic.

Is the statement true?

I know the statement "$G$ be an Abelian  group of order $n$. $G$ has atmost one subgroup of order of every divisor of $n$. Then G is cyclic." is true.

Can anyone please confirm me whether my statement is true or not?

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1302635/a-finite-group-which-has-a-unique-subgroup-of-order-d-for-each-d-mid-n) link

Answer (score -2):

I have copied this answer from the answer of https://math.stackexchange.com/users/223481/censi-li

Let $\varphi$ denote the Euler function, then you constraint forces that $G$ has **at most** $\varphi(d)$ elements of order $d$ for each $d\mid n$. But $\sum_{d\mid n}\varphi(d)=n$, so $G$ must contain **exactly** $\varphi(d)$ elements of order $d$ for each $d\mid n$, in particular, $G$ contains an element of order $n$.

Comment: If you're going to copy [someone else's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1302655/169852) verbatim, you should at least cite the original author.